# How to import only types, not instances?

Tags: c#, .net, list, mef, instantiation

I'm importing DLLs which export an `IPlugin` class by using MEF (System.ComponentModel.Composition) with the `[ImportMany(typeof(IPlugin))]` attribute.

Here's the code I use to fetch the extensions:

```
AggregateCatalog catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(AppDataHelper.ExeDir + "/Module/"));
CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
CompositionBatch batch = new CompositionBatch();
batch.AddPart(this);
```

However, as far as I see, the corresponding property will hold instances afterwards.

How do I import only types (preferrably `Type` objects) of the extensions so I can create instances however I like myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, MEF works by creating a single instance of every compatible and exported type it finds.

The easiest way around this is to import **factories** and then use them to create the actual instances.

The interface would look something like:

```
interface IPluginFactory
{
    IPlugin CreateInstance();
    string TypeName {get;}
}
```

And then you search the MEF populated collection of factories for the right type name and call its `CreateInstance` function.

Comment: Could you explain this in a little more detail, please?

Comment: @Cobra_Fast I put in an example factory interface, does that make sense? I'm happy to provide as many details as needed (I've done this a *few* times :) so let me know if you would like more!)

Comment: So all I do is export a factory, through which I can later instantiate the actual extension instances?

Comment: @Cobra_Fast, Exactly. I use the "TypeName" property to look for it. It doesn't actually have to be the type name, it can be whatever you want to associate with that class/factory.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a catalog, then work from there (without composition batch) and find the relevant type from there yourself.